# Finding the solutions of nonlinear system with absolute value

Tags: absolute-value, nonlinear-system

I need to show that the initial value problem:

$\dot{x}=|x|^{1/2}$

$x(0)=0$

has 4 different solutions through the point (0,0). The problem also says that I have to sketch the solutions in the $(t,x)$-plane.

My solution:

So basically I have no issue with solving the problem, I just want to make sure I am not missing 2 extra solutions, or if I am just misinterpreting the problem.

After solving the first equation with elemental calculus, I get: $x(t)=\pm t^2/4$. But these are just 2 curves. However when I do the plot, the point (0,0) is arrived by 4 different curves: $\pm t^2/4$, split in half, and with other two cases of $t>0$ and $t<0$. So is my solution correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: This is an example of an equation with extraneous solutions not given by the solution formula:

Consider $y=(x-a)^2$ for ($x>a$) and 0 otherwise. Then, $y' = x-a = \sqrt{y}$, this certainly solves it (for $x>0$ at least). So there's a lot of solutions to this equation.

Comment: But wouldn't $a=0$, given the initial condition: $x(0)=0$

Comment: Take a = (say) 0.5.

Then (I defined $y$ to be 0 for $x<a$), so we'd have a curve which is 0 between 0 and a half, and behaves quadratically for $x>0.5$

(Out of interest, the person who defined this to me for the first time called this example the 'lazy student' example, if you plot the graph of the students position vs time, he can get up "whenever he wants" between 0 and 1)

Comment: Have a terrible looking graph to explain this slightly better: http://i.snag.gy/a5imG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The initial value problem
$$
x'=|x|^{1/2}, \quad x(0)=0,
$$
does not have $4$ but infinite many solutions.

Nevertheless, the $4$ ones you are referring to are:
$$
\psi_1(t)=0,\quad \psi_2(t)=\frac{t^2}{4}\mathrm{sgn}\,t, \quad \psi_3=\max\{\psi_1,\psi_2\}
\quad\text{and}\quad \psi_4=\min\{\psi_1,\psi_2\}.
$$

Comment: $\{\psi_3,\psi_4\}$ look interesting! but I have no idea why I should even include them. Aren't they redundant with $\{\psi_1,\psi_2\}$?